# Remove empty elements in nested list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a long list from testing data. It looks like

```
pts={{{{},{}, ..., {{t1, a1, b1, c1}}, ..., {}},{{},{}, ..., {{ti, ai, bi, ci}}, ..., {}}, ..., {{},{}, ..., {{tj, aj, bj, cj}}, ..., {}}},{{{},{}, ..., {{tk, ak, bk, ck}}, ..., {}},{{},{}, ..., {{tm, am, bm, cm}}, ..., {}}, ..., {{},{}, ..., {{tn, an, bn, cn}}, ..., {}}}, ..., {{{},{}, ..., {{tp, ap, bp, cp}}, ..., {}}, {{},{}, ..., {{tq, aq, bq, cq}}, ..., {}}, ..., {{},{}, ..., {{tl, al, bl, cl}}, ..., {}}}}`
```

in which all `{}` are empty lists, generated by `Nothing`, and the sub-lists like `{t, a, b, c}` include numerical values `t`, `a`, `b` and `c`. I have to remove all empty elements and keep those sub-lists with numerical values in the form of

```
ptsnew={{t1, a1, b1, c1}, {ti, ai, bi, ci}, {tj, aj, bj, cj}, {tk, ak, bk, ck},{tm, am, bm, cm}, {tn, an, bn, cn}, {tp, ap, bp, cp}, {tq, aq, bq, cq}, {tl, al, bl, cl}}`
```

I have tried `DeleteCases[pts, {}, 3]`, which however only removes the empty list on level-3.

Comment: Strongly related SO thread: "[Efficient way to remove empty lists from lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6562902/590388)"

Comment: Flatten[pts //. {} -> Nothing] // Partition[#, 4] &

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
pts = {{}, {}, {{t1, a1, b1, c1}}, {}, {{ti, ai, bi, ci}}}

(*  {{}, {}, {{t1, a1, b1, c1}}, {}, {{ti, ai, bi, ci}}}  *)

pts /. {} -> Nothing

(* {{{t1, a1, b1, c1}}, {{ti, ai, bi, ci}}}  *)
```

If you have there nested empty lists you will need to apply the procedure several times. For example, let your list be:

```
pts = {{{}}, {{{{}}}}, {{t1, a1, b1, c1}}, {}, {{ti, ai, bi, ci}}};
```

Then the repeated application of the above rule can look as follows:

```
FixedPoint[ReplaceAll[#, {} -> Nothing] &, pts]

(*  {{{t1, a1, b1, c1}}, {{ti, ai, bi, ci}}}  *)
```

Have fun!

Comment: Please note there are 4 layers of `{}` before reaching the non-empty elements in my example. Your answer actually give the same result as `DeleteCases[pts, {}, 3]` for my example.

Comment: It almost achieves my aim! But as mentioned in my post, `pts` is a really long list, which even include a skeletonizing `OutputSizeLimit`Skeleton[100], for example. This makes your method not work for those skeletonized sub-lists. Is there any way to make it take effect into the ignored elements, instead of must clicking _show more_ below the long list to expand it before applying `FixedPoint`. Thank you very much!

Comment: I am not familiar with skeletonizing. However, as I see your desired form of the result, maybe a good idea would be to first apply `Flatten` to the list and then the operation that I proposed.

Comment: Your `FixedPoint` approach is equivalent to `pts //. {} :> Nothing`, i.e., using `ReplaceRepeated`

Answer (score 6):

`pts = {{{{}, {}, {{t1, a1, b1, c1}}, {}}, {{}, {}, {{ti, ai, bi,  ci}}, {}}, {{}, {}, {{tj, aj, bj, cj}}, {}}}, {{{}, {}, {{tk,  ak, bk, ck}}, {}}, {{}, {}, {{tm, am, bm,  cm}}, {}}, {{}, {}, {{tn, an, bn, cn}}, {}}}, {{{}, {}, {{tp,  ap, bp, cp}}, {}}, {{}, {}, {{tq, aq, bq,  cq}}, {}}, {{}, {}, {{tl, al, bl, cl}}, {}}}}`

```
 DeleteCases[pts, {}, Infinity]//Flatten[#, 3]&
```

[image]

An alternative is to use Cases with a pattern that matches the types of the relevant sub lists.

```
Cases[pts, {_Symbol, _Symbol, _Symbol, _Symbol}, Infinity]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

```
Level[pts, {-2}] /. {} -> Nothing
```

> ```
> {{t1, a1, b1, c1}, {ti, ai, bi, ci}, {tj, aj, bj, cj}, {tk, ak, bk, 
>   ck}, {tm, am, bm, cm}, {tn, an, bn, cn}, {tp, ap, bp, cp}, {tq, aq, 
>   bq, cq}, {tl, al, bl, cl}}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Simple case with `Case`

```
a = {{}, {}, {{t1, a1, b1, c1}}, {}, {{ti, ai, bi, ci}}};

Cases[la, {{__?AtomQ}}]
```

{{{t1, a1, b1, c1}}, {{ti, ai, bi, ci}}}

Nested case with `Case`

```
lb = {{{}}, {{{{}}}}, {{t1, a1, b1, c1}}, {}, {{ti, ai, bi, ci}}};

Cases[lb, {{__?AtomQ}}]
```

{{{t1, a1, b1, c1}}, {{ti, ai, bi, ci}}}

Answer (score 1):

```
la = {{}, {}, {{t1, a1, b1, c1}}, {}, {{ti, ai, bi, ci}}};

lb = {{{}}, {{{{}}}}, {{t1, a1, b1, c1}}, {}, {{ti, ai, bi, ci}}};
```

---

Grabbing the @eldo's examples and using `Select`:

```
Select[la, Level[#, {-1}] =!= {} &]

(*{{{t1, a1, b1, c1}}, {{ti, ai, bi, ci}}}*)

Select[lb, Level[#, {-1}] =!= {} &]

(*{{{t1, a1, b1, c1}}, {{ti, ai, bi, ci}}}*)
```

Or using `FixedPoint` and `DeleteCases`:

```
FixedPoint[DeleteCases[#, {}, ∞] &, la]

(*{{{t1, a1, b1, c1}}, {{ti, ai, bi, ci}}}*)

 FixedPoint[DeleteCases[#, {}, ∞] &, lb]

(*{{{t1, a1, b1, c1}}, {{ti, ai, bi, ci}}}*)
```