# How can I remove empty lists { } from a nested list?

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement, pattern-matching

I have a list:

```
list={{{1},{2},{1,2},{1,2,3},{},{}},{{2},{3},{}}}
```

I would like to remove the empty lists `{}` to get:

```
{{{1},{2},{1,2},{1,2,3}},{{2},{3}}}
```

How can I automate this using *Mathematica* ?

Comment: Strongly related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/261187/1871

Comment: also [strongly related](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/34801/106)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Using ReplaceAll (which can also be written /.) we can replace all the empty lists { } with Nothing.

```
list /. {} -> Nothing

{{{1}, {2}, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}}, {{2}, {3}}}
```

Answer (score 10):

Using `DeleteCases`:

```
list1 = {{{1}, {2}, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {}, {}}, {{2}, {3}, {}}};

DeleteCases[list1, {}, 2]

(*{{{1}, {2}, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}}, {{2}, {3}}}*)
```

Considering the @Nasser's observation, we can generalize this strategy introducing the depth of the array to apply it in more complicated cases, as I show below:

```
DeleteCases[#, {}, Depth@#] &@list1

(*{{{1}, {2}, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}}, {{2}, {3}}}*)

list2 = {{{1}, {2}, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {}, {}}, {3, {{{2}, {3}, {}}}}};

DeleteCases[#, {}, Depth@#] &@list2

(*{{{1}, {2}, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}}, {3, {{{2}, {3}}}}}*)
```

**Thanks to Nasser for this valuable observation.**

Another way, as suggested by @AndreasLauschke is to put `Infinity` instead of `2`:

```
DeleteCases[list1, {}, ∞]

(*{{{1}, {2}, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}}, {{2}, {3}}}*)
```

Comment: fyi, this does not work on general. It works for the input given. For example, if the input was `list={{{1},{2},{1,2},{1,2,3},{},{}},{3,{{{2},{3},{}}}}};` then `DeleteCases[list,{},2]` does not remove the `{}`. Screen shot  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPVFq.png)

Comment: Use Infinity instead of 2

Comment: @AndreasLauschke You're right, thanks for the suggestion. :-)

Answer (score 7):

```
list = {{{1}, {2}, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {}, {}}, {{2}, {3}, {}}};

p = Position[{}] @ list;
```

{{1, 5}, {1, 6}, {2, 3}}

```
Delete[p] @ list
```

{{{1}, {2}, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}}, {{2}, {3}}}

```
MapAt[Nothing, p] @ list
```

{{{1}, {2}, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}}, {{2}, {3}}}

```
ReplacePart[p -> Nothing] @ list
```

{{{1}, {2}, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}}, {{2}, {3}}}

```
ReplaceAt[_ :> Nothing, p] @ list
```

{{{1}, {2}, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}}, {{2}, {3}}}

Answer (score 4):

```
list //. {} -> Sequence[]
```

and

```
list //. {} :> Unevaluated[## &[]]
```

both give

> {{{1}, {2}, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}}, {{2}, {3}}}

Comment: (+1) I hadn't seen the second one, nicely done mate! :-)

Comment: @E.Chan-López thanks a lot! :-)